# Prevent code cells from wrapping text after exporting Jupyter Lab to HTML

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I have a Jupyter Lab notebook that looks great when I edit it on my machine. However, I will share it with others via a simple "File > Export Notebook As > Export Notebook to HTML."

After doing this, all the code cells use word wrap and look very ugly, such that I'm sure people will not even want to look at them :(

Can I disable code cell word wrap when exporting to HTML? I've done some exhaustive Googling, but didn't see this question. Thanks! :)

Here is my view. Looks great!

[image: desc 1]

But here it is after exporting to HTML:

[image: desc 2]

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out on my own, thrilled!

I did not change Jupyter Lab's exporting behavior. Rather, I edited the .html output directly the fix the issue.

Search the .html code and you will see this:

```
/* Word-wrap output correctly.  This is the CSS3 spelling, though Firefox seems
   to not honor it correctly.  Webkit browsers (Chrome, rekonq, Safari) do.
 */
pre,
code,
kbd,
samp {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Simply change "pre-wrap" to "pre" and you will see desired behavior in every code box going forward. See screenshot:

[solved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIuXh.png)

Comment: My solution only works in Chrome/Firefox, not IE/Edge.